# How to start new activity inside viewpager tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, tabs, android-viewpager

I am coding a tabbed app in android using ViewPager. Currently, I have an activity, called RSC Activity, that I want to open up inside a tab. (RSCActivity implements onCreateView and has a UI of its own). My main problem is a button that has a click listener set in RSCActivity, cannot be implemented in the tabbed layout, because the click listener method is a method of a class extended from RSC Activity.

Code-
I start RSCActivity with the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ..
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RSCActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            ..
      }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2= new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3= new Tab3 ();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Tab1";
            case 1:
                return "Tab2";
            case 2:
                return "Tab3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
    public static class Tab1 extends Fragment{

        public Tab1() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_rsc, container, false);
             return rootView;
        }

    }
}
```

In the RSCActivity, I set the view and click listener like so,

```
public class RSCActivity extends BleProfileServiceReadyActivity<RSCService.RSCBinder> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreateView(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_rsc);
        final Button connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_connect);
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //connectButton.setText("Clicked");
                onConnectClicked(v);
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

If I don't call setContentView in RSCActivity, then I am not able to set the click listener, because onConnectClicked is part of RSCActivity, but this opens up a separate screen outside of the tabbed view. So as it stands now, I have to open a new screen to click CONNECT, but I want the UI to open up in Tab1 and be able to click CONNECT.

As mentioned, I cannot move the onConnectClicked into MainActivity. Going the route of making the activity into a service doesn't seem feasible, because RSCActivity extends another activity, which in turn extends another activity, etc. I need RSCActivity to be running when I am inside Tab1.

Thanks in advance